# slack file upload fails on CentOs Server

Tags: python-2.7, centos, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Slack via API and the same script works fine locally (file correctly uploaded), but fails when run from Server, returning:

```
{u'ok': False, u'error': u'no_file_data'}
```

here are the 2 functions used (one to write content to tmp folder, the other one to upload it to the chosen channel)

```
def writeToFile():
    with open(output_file, 'rb') as rf:
        with open('/tmp/' + output_file, "w") as wf:
            wf.write(rf.read())


def upload_file():
    with open('/tmp/' + output_file) as file_content:
        r = client.api_call(
            "files.upload",
            channels=channel,
            file=file_content,
            filetype='xlsx',
            title=output_file
        )
        logging.info(r)
```

It seems the file gets correctly written to tmp folder with writeToFile, but the issue happens in `upload_file`.

I  can read the content too as

```
with open('/tmp/' + output_file) as file_content:
    print file_content.read()
```

prints correctly the file content. So the problem is with the api call.

Locally I have MacOS and server Linux Centos. I'm using Python 2.7.10 on both.

Comment: Kindly include the error you are getting

Comment: @CalebNjiiri sorry it wasn't clear. the response I get from the api_call is when run from server is {u'ok': False, u'error': u'no_file_data'}. I can get that printing r in upload_file

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion here https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/198 I realised server had slackclient 1.0.0, when locally was 1.3.0.

Installing version 1.3.0 solved the issue.